# How do I load a clang-tidy project in CLion

Tags: cmake, clion, llvm-clang

I'm new to CLion and kind of new to the LLVM-project source code and  I'm working on adding a check to clang tidy.
Since learning the different AST Matchers available is a bit tricky in the beginning I want to make use of an IDE to get some help with auto completion.
So I'm trying to open a Clang tidy CMake project in CLion but I keep getting CMake errors and I don't think I'm using the right CMakeLists.txt but I can't figure out which one to use.

How exactly do I load the Clang tidy source as a CMake project in CLion and make it suggest AST Matchers?

What I have tried so far:
 * In Clion I opened the repo named llvm-project as a project.
 * In the project explorer I then found '''./clang/CMakeLists.txt'''
 * I right clicked '''./clang/CMakeLists.txt''' and clicked "Load as CMake project"

The errors I get are:

```
/snap/clion/92/bin/cmake/linux/bin/cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/clang -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/clang++ -G 
"CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles" /home/kim/src/llvm-project/clang
-- Linker detection: GNU ld
-- Building with -fPIC
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:117 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    LLVMDistributionSupport


-- Clang version: 6.0.0
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:863 (llvm_distribution_add_targets):
  Unknown CMake command "llvm_distribution_add_targets".
```

Comment: "I keep getting CMake errors and I don't think I'm using the right CMakeLists.txt but I can't figure out which one to use" - It is difficult to say what you are doing wrong if you don't describe your actions and errors you got.

Comment: There should be a way that people usually do this that could be described without knowing exactly how I tried to do it;  but I'll add a description of my last attempt for anyone who want to explain exactly why that went wrong instead of how they usually do it.

Comment: The project's [README](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/master/README.md) clearly states that you need to run **top-level** `CMakeLists.txt`, not the one from the `clang` subdirectory. For choose which llvm project(s) to build, set `LLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS` variable accordingly.

Comment: I'v read that README many times but I don't see how it says that. Actually there isn't even a "top level" '''CMakeLists.txt''' in llvm-project.
All I see that README explaining is how to build the entire llvm project from command line and I already know how to do that. What I want to know is how to load a project in CLion so that I get code completion, that README says nothing about that.

Comment: I got it to work. I tried loading the entire project, i.e. llvm-project/llvm/CMakeLists.txt, that wasn't enough though. I hadn't realized the project in work had to be build **by CLion**, as part of loading, for code completion to work (that might seem stupid of me but I never used IDE:s much before)
After opening the llvm project, instead of clang-tidy directly, I had to do the following:  
* Click File->Settings  
* Open Build, Execution, Deploymenty->CMake
* Edit "CMake options" with: -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS="clang;clang-tools-extra;libcxx;libcxxabi"